# Sql, validation to check a list allowing a delimiter

Tags: sql

I want to create a validation in SQL that will check for a value or combination of values that can be delimited with a semi-colon from a list of 3 possible combinations of 'Apples''Oranges' 'Bananas'.

In the example below the validation should pass for the first options but fail for the last

```
CREATE TABLE Test1(A varchar (50));

INSERT INTO Test1 VALUES ('Apples;Oranges;Bananas');
INSERT INTO Test1 VALUES ('Apples');
INSERT INTO Test1 VALUES ('Apples;Eggs');
```

Comment: Never, ever store data like that. It will only cause you lots of problems.

Comment: This is simpler and more maintainable if you use either one row per item, or one column per item (if the number of items is never going to be more than 3). Delimited string lists are not a happy medium for a relational database.